# How to make body move follow a orbit?

Tags: android, andengine

guys.

I'm a newbie, i want to create a sprite( with body 2D) move follow a orbit. Can u tell me how to do this???

```
planSprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(10f, planSprite.myPath, new PlanePathModifierListener(this.mEngine, planSprite)), 1));
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use EntityModifiers to move Bodies. You will have to create something similar to a gravity field, probably using areas where specified forces are applied to the body.